# How to read stdin keys in rust with termion using dynamic char values?

Tags: input, rust, terminal, match, stdin

I have the following code to read user input keys from terminal using `termion`

```
use std::io::{stdin, stdout};
use termion::event::Key;

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    let stdin = stdin();
    
    let char_from_config = 'e';

    for c in stdin.keys() {
        match c.unwrap() {
            Key::Char('q') => {
                break;
            }
            Key::Char('h') => {
                // do something
            }
            Key::Char('l') => {
                // do something else
            }
            _ => {}
        }

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
```

What I would want to do is to read not just `Key::Char('q')` but some other dynamic character value, which I collect from somewhere else, like `Key::Char(char_from_config)`, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Is there a way to paste a variable containing `char` instead of an actual `'char'` to `match` arms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a match arm `Key(c) => ...`, `c` becomes part of a pattern that match will match against and if value matched this enum variant c will be equal to whatever this variant holds. You however want to say "match only if it's `Key` variant with this given value". You have two options how to do it.

1. You can either have `const` value (you probably **don't** want to do that):

```rust
const CHAR_FROM_CONFIG: char = 'e';

match ... {
    Key(CHAR_FROM_CONFIG) => (),
    _ => ()
}
```

2. Or use a match guard (you probably **do** want to do that):

```rust
let char_from_config = 'e';

match ... {
    // c will match here any character, but this arm will succeed only
    // when it will be equal to char_from_config 
    Key(c) if c == char_from_config => (),
    _ => ()
}
```